# two array dimensional ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException and NullPointerException

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, indexoutofboundsexception

i wrote a code for calculating some weights. they are integer weights.
and i need to save them in every time the button is clicked.
please help me. i cant see why the compiler gives me an error when i try to push the button for the second time. here is my complete code:

```
    public class TrainingActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText etIn1, etIn2, etDesired;
    private TextView prevInput;

    int W[][] = new int[2][];
    int X[][] = new int[30][];

    int w0=0, w1=0, w2=0, p=1, sum=0, clicks=0;

    private Button nxtData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.training_activity);

    View backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background);
    Drawable background = backgroundImage.getBackground();
    background.setAlpha(40);

    etIn1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput1);
    etIn2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput2);
    etDesired = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDesired);

    prevInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prevInput);

    nxtData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextData);
    nxtData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int sum = 0;
            ++clicks;

            int intetIn1 = Integer.parseInt(etIn1.getText().toString());
            int intetIn2 = Integer.parseInt(etIn2.getText().toString());
            int intetDesired = Integer.parseInt(etDesired.getText().toString());

            X[clicks-1] = new int[] {intetIn1, intetIn2, 1};

            prevInput.setText("Last Inputs: (" + intetIn1 + ", " + intetIn2 +
                    ", " + intetDesired + ")");

            if(clicks == 1) {
            if(intetDesired == 1) {
                W[0] = new int[] {intetIn1, intetIn2, 1};
                W[1] = W[0];
            } else if(intetDesired == (-1)){
                W[0] = new int[] {-intetIn1, -intetIn2, -1};
                W[1] = W[0];
            }
            } else if(clicks > 1) {                 
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    sum = sum + W[clicks-1][i] * X[clicks-1][i];
                } if(sum>0 && intetDesired==1) {
                    W[clicks] = W[clicks-1];
                } else if(sum<0 && intetDesired==(-1)) {
                    W[clicks] = W[clicks-1];
                } else if(sum<=0 && intetDesired==1) {
                    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                    W[clicks][i] = W[clicks-1][i] + X[clicks-1][i];
                }
                } else if(sum>=0 && intetDesired==(-1)) {
                    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                        W[clicks][i] = W[clicks-1][i] - X[clicks-1][i];
                    }
                }
            } 

            etIn1.setText("");
            etIn2.setText("");
            etDesired.setText("");

        }
    });


}}
```

and here is the exception it throws:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
```

**UPDATEEEEEEEE**
i fixed the problem with arrayindexoutofboundexception by changing W[2][] to W[20][]. but in some clicks it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and it's not clear in which clicks. sometimes it's in the second click. or some times it's in fourth click. please help.

Comment: Debug your code - an array of length 2 has indexes 0 and 1 - you are trying to access index 2 and so the program quite rightly throws a useful, clear and meaningful exception to help you fix the issue.

Comment: I guess you are getting at this line `sum = sum + W[clicks-1][i] * X[clicks-1][i]; `

Comment: Yes you are right. The W array is the problem. Actually i thought that i put 20 rows for that. But it was 2 only. Thank you. I think it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W[clicks] = W[clicks - 1];

in above line, you have get error because you have only define size of the array

**int W[][] = new int[2][];**

so it assigned W[0][] and  W[1][] only

When click on second time variable clicks value is 2 then compiler gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

**EDITED.............................................................**

you have got null value because of your bad logic and not proper way to build two dimensional array. Pls use debug tool to find the actual problem to implement logic and use two dimensional array like below example in java or android:

```
 List<List<Integer>> triangle = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

List<Integer> row1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(1);
row1.add(2);
triangle.add(row1);

List<Integer> row2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(2);
row2.add(3);row2.add(4);
triangle.add(row2);

triangle.add(Arrays.asList(6,5,7));
triangle.add(Arrays.asList(4,1,8,3));

System.out.println("Size = "+ triangle.size());
for (int i=0; i<triangle.size();i++)
    System.out.println(triangle.get(i));
```

Comment: Thank you man. I thought that i put 20 instead of 2. Ill check it out and tell you the results. But i think it will fix the problem for sure.

Comment: how may click you have perform to calculation?
If you put 20 instead of 2 than click 19 times and than after given same error. So implement another logic

Comment: im assuming that user is gonna click less than 19. but can you tell me a way to buil two dimensional arrays based on exact clicks? theres no way. at least i cant think of.

Comment: the problem is. i fixed the 2. and made it 20. but some times it gives me java.lang.NullPointerException i really dont know what should i do. please help.